# Allow user to enter unpublished content from the site in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I have a content type "User Bio" in my Drupal 7 site. On my site I created a form with all the fields in User Bio for the anonymous user to fill.

Now when the user enters and submits this information I want the node of "User Bio" type to be created but it should be unpublished. When the admin reviews, only then it can be published.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) Module might be a good candidate for your requirement.

> Workbench Moderation adds arbitrary moderation states to Drupal core's
>   "unpublished" and "published" node states, and affects the behavior of
>   node revisions when nodes are published. Moderation states are tracked
>   per-revision; rather than moderating nodes, Workbench Moderation
>   moderates revisions.

But if are considering to use user bio to create user profiles after admin publishes the user bio content, I would recommend you to use User entity instead of having a separate content type.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to set the content type to not be published by default, by simply editing the content type, and un-checking "Published" in the lower tab menu.

This will create the content unpublished, and from there you can handle the approval process however you'd like.

Comment: Perfect! That's a very easy way. One more question. What's a better way for creating a node through a Theme Front End Site. I actually never did anything like that.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @user219492, if you have a new question, use the "Ask question" button. This is not a forum, so please do use the comment feature to ask questions.